# How to make a "If all of these 15 signs have been clicked and then broken do this?" with /execute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make an Easter egg hunt where you find 15 signs, in any order right-clicked (and then break) they display a chat message with a counter on how many signs you right-clicked (and then broke)

I need a command that is "If this player right-clicks and then breaks all 15 of the easter eggs, do this"
Ex:

> You found 2/15 easter eggs!

you right-click and then break the next sign:

> You found 3/15 easter eggs!

and so on...

Version: 1.19.2

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Comment: Does is matter in what order the signs are broken, or can any sign be found at any time? Also what Minecraft version are you on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could detect when the signs break separately.

This means you would need to repeat it for every sign, but I wasn't able to figure out another way.

Minecraft **1.12.1**

Make scoreboard to track the signs:

```
scoreboard objectives add EasterEggs dummy
```

You would detect when the block that the sign is in is air:

```
execute if block 1 56 -4 air run scoreboard players add @a EasterEggs 1
```

This command block is repeating and needs Redstone, it will execute at the sign when it's air, then the following command will be a conditional chain command block. This will tell the player the score:

```
execute as @a run title @s actionbar ["",{"text":"You Found "},{"score":{"name":"@a","objective":"EasterEggs"}},{"text":"/15 Easter Eggs!"}]
```

[image: Score]

The last command will be in another conditional chain command block, removing the Redstone that powers the Commandblock chain:

```
setblock 5 56 -4 air
```

The coordinates are simply next to the repeating Commandblock.

[image: Easter Egg Command Blocks]

Here is a demonstration:
[image: Demonstration]

---

**Then for the sign:**

Minecraft **1.20:**

I used this command to give myself a sign that replaces itself with air when clicked:

```
give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{front_text:{messages:['{"text":"Easter egg","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"setblock ~ ~ ~ air"}}','{"text":""}','{"text":""}','{"text":""}']}}} 1
```

You can change the text to your liking within the `"text":"<Your text here>"` parts.

Minecraft **1.19:**

```
/give @p oak_sign{BlockEntityTag:{Text1:'{"text":"Easter Egg","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"Setblock <x> <y> <z> <block>"}}'}} 1
```

And for each line, you do `Text<n>` where `n` is the line you want your text to be, ex: `Text1:'{"text":"","clickEvent":{}}',Text2:'{"text":""}',Text3:'{}'`

Comment: +1 Great answer! How about a command that doesn't replace the sign with a block and just leaves the sign?

Comment: Well, make the first command block `Impulse` and `Need Redstone`, remove the execute part of it, and leave `scoreboard players add @a EasterEggs 1`. Then remove the Redstone block next to the command block. Then remove the 3rd command block. The sign will then have the command: `setblock <x> <y> <z> redstone`, so when you click it it will place the redstone, but if you click it again it wont be able to place a redstone block.

Comment: Then you would need to still have command blocks for each sign and change the coordinates for the sign command.

Comment: Smart! But Im on version 1.19.2

Comment: Alright, I have updated the answer to also work for 1.19. because the only difference is that signs now in 1.20 can have text on both front and back, I simply included the 1.19 give command for the sign.